# How to set the zoom ratio of an hyperlink with the new target on HTML

Tags: javascript, html, zooming

I have an hyperlink including a pdf that opens with a new tab like below,

[Download My Resume](http://www.erhanyasar.com.tr/files/CV_ErhanYasar.pdf)

```
<a href="files/CV_ErhanYasar.pdf" target="_blank">Download My Resume</a>
```

It's right now opening with %300 or something zoomed with Safari. Can I set a specific zoom ratio with the opening window or tab?

PS: I searched for  tag's target attribute and similars but it's not included as I dogged further.

Comment: Surely that will be a setting on your adobe reader safari plugin rather than actual code

Comment: I thought there might be some solution to implement this without letting user to handle.